# Why graphic programs like as screenshot makers or screen recorders not works in KDE?

Tags: ubuntu, kde-plasma

I have install the latest version of KDE Neon (also i try kubuntu).
And tried to use programs like Flameshot, SimpleScreenRecorder, OBS, Kazam or they alternatives. And all they record black screen instead of desktop picture. Hovewer, the most interesting of this situations is that all these programs correctlu works on Ubuntu with Gnome.
Do you have an idea why it's happening?

Sysinfo:

> - KDE Neon (or Kubuntu) latest version
> - AMD Ryzen 9 3900X
> - AMD Radeon RX 6600
> - Several 4K (Ultra HD) displays

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site for programming questions specifically.  This may be a better fit for https://askubuntu.com/, though do check their [on topic page](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) first.

Answer (score -1):

The info you are providing is not enough. I suspect that you are using Wayland. So make sure you have the `xdg-desktop-portal` and `xdg-desktop-portal-kde` installed (these are the Arch package name and in your distro they might be a bit different).

I would also suggest that you provide system info with the following as it provide most of the information needed for tracking such issue:

```bash
inxi --system --graphics
```